# Getting one row for each leading row in a partition that has the same value on another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I had extracted the `LEAD()` with a partition in a table but realised I have rows where a column has duplicated values and it turns out that the "lead" I actually need for a row is each of those. So for each leading row in the partition right before a row, I want to duplicate the row with one of each leading rows leading value. How could I achieve that?

This is what my data looks like:

| id | part | col | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | faa |
| 2 | a | 2 | fab |
| 3 | a | 2 | fac |
| 4 | a | 2 | fab |
| 5 | a | 3 | fab |
| 6 | a | 3 | fad |
| 7 | a | 4 | fae |
| 8 | b | 4 | faa |
| 9 | b | 9 | faa |
| 10 | b | 9 | fac |
| 11 | b | 6 | faa |
| 12 | c | 1 | faa |
| 13 | c | 2 | faa |
| 14 | c | 3 | fad |
| 15 | c | 4 | fac |

The `id` column is no unique key but a row ID.

What I did was a `LEAD(val) OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY id)` which gives me:

| id | part | col | val | lead |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | faa | NULL |
| 2 | a | 2 | fab | faa |
| 3 | a | 2 | fac | fab |
| 4 | a | 2 | fab | fac |
| 5 | a | 3 | fab | fab |
| 6 | a | 3 | fad | fab |
| 7 | a | 4 | fae | fad |
| 8 | b | 4 | faa | NULL |
| 9 | b | 9 | faa | faa |
| 10 | b | 9 | fac | faa |
| 11 | b | 6 | faa | fac |
| 12 | c | 1 | faa | NULL |
| 13 | c | 2 | faa | faa |
| 14 | c | 3 | fad | faa |
| 15 | c | 4 | fac | fad |

But what I need is this (I hope I made no mistake, please ask if something row seems weird):

| id | part | col | val | lead | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | faa | NULL |  |
| 2 | a | 2 | fab | faa |  |
| 3 | a | 2 | fac | faa |  |
| 4 | a | 2 | fab | faa |  |
| 5 | a | 3 | fab | fab | value from first LEADing row in partition a with col=2 |
| 5 | a | 3 | fab | fac | value from second LEADing row in partition a with col=2 |
| 5 | a | 3 | fab | fab | value from third LEADing row in partition a with col=2 |
| 6 | a | 3 | fad | fab |  |
| 7 | a | 4 | fae | fab | value from first LEADing row in partition with col=3 |
| 7 | a | 4 | fae | fad | value from second LEADing row in partition with col=3 |
| 8 | b | 4 | faa | NULL |  |
| 9 | b | 9 | faa | faa |  |
| 10 | b | 9 | fac | faa |  |
| 11 | b | 6 | faa | faa | value from first LEADing row in partition with col=9 |
| 11 | b | 6 | faa | fac | value from second LEADing row in partition with col=9 |
| 12 | c | 1 | faa | NULL |  |
| 13 | c | 2 | faa | faa |  |
| 14 | c | 3 | fad | faa |  |
| 15 | c | 4 | fac | fad |  |

Comment: What you are calling `lead()` looks like `lag()` to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of functions.  The first gets the lagged value and the second spreads it over the group:

```
select t.*,
       max(prev_val) filter (where prev_col is distinct from col) over (partition by part order by id) as desired_value
from (select t.*,
             lag(val) over (partition by part order by id) as prev_val,
             lag(col) over (partition by part order by id) as prev_col
      from t
     ) t;
```

You could also use a lateral join.  Assuming that `col` has sequential values:

```
select t.*, t2.val as prev_val
from t left join lateral
     (select t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.part = t.part and
            t2.col = t.col - 1
      order by t2.id desc
      limit 1
     ) t2
     on 1=1;
```